# Creating a "First" identifier in an SQL query

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I need to be able to identify the first time a set of rows, a question set, occur in a view of a table. Not sure how to frame the question clearly so will try and set it out below.

Example data

```
+-----------+------------+--------+------+----------+--------+
| Reference |    Date    | PerRef | QSet | Question | Answer |
+-----------+------------+--------+------+----------+--------+
|         1 | 01/01/2015 | a      | QS1  | Q1       | A1     |
|         1 | 01/01/2015 | a      | QS1  | Q2       | A2     |
|         1 | 01/01/2015 | a      | QS1  | Q3       | A3     |
|         2 | 02/01/2015 | a      | QS1  | Q1       | A1     |
|         2 | 02/01/2015 | a      | QS1  | Q2       | A2     |
|         2 | 02/01/2015 | a      | QS1  | Q3       | A3     |
|         3 | 02/01/2015 | b      | QS2  | Q1       | A1     |
|         3 | 02/01/2015 | b      | QS2  | Q2       | A2     |
|         3 | 02/01/2015 | b      | QS2  | Q3       | A3     |
|         4 | 02/01/2015 | b      | QS3  | Q1       | A1     |
|         4 | 02/01/2015 | b      | QS3  | Q2       | A2     |
|         4 | 02/01/2015 | b      | QS3  | Q3       | A3     |
+-----------+------------+--------+------+----------+--------+
```

For this table I would want to generate a new column on a select query which would look like this:

```
+-----------+------------+---------+-------+----------+--------+----------+--------+
| Reference |   Date     | PerRef  | QSet  | Question | Answer | Earliest | Latest |
+-----------+------------+---------+-------+----------+--------+----------+--------+
|         1 | 01/01/2015 | a       | QS1   | Q1       | A1     |        1 |      2 |
|         1 | 01/01/2015 | a       | QS1   | Q2       | A2     |        1 |      2 |
|         1 | 01/01/2015 | a       | QS1   | Q3       | A3     |        1 |      2 |
|         2 | 02/01/2015 | a       | QS1   | Q1       | A1     |        2 |      1 |
|         2 | 02/01/2015 | a       | QS1   | Q2       | A2     |        2 |      1 |
|         2 | 02/01/2015 | a       | QS1   | Q3       | A3     |        2 |      1 |
|         3 | 02/01/2015 | b       | QS2   | Q1       | A1     |        1 |      1 |
|         3 | 02/01/2015 | b       | QS2   | Q2       | A2     |        1 |      1 |
|         3 | 02/01/2015 | b       | QS2   | Q3       | A3     |        1 |      1 |
|         4 | 05/01/2015 | b       | QS3   | Q1       | A1     |        1 |      1 |
|         4 | 05/01/2015 | b       | QS3   | Q2       | A2     |        1 |      1 |
|         4 | 05/01/2015 | b       | QS3   | Q3       | A3     |        1 |      1 |
+-----------+------------+---------+-------+----------+--------+----------+--------+
```

I have this in both Earliest and Latest as it then lets me pull back the first completed or the latest. Generally queries will be to bring back just one of one type of question set against a person, either the first completed or he latest. Having both these will of course enable the option to bring back the earliest OR latest and see the change between the two.

So to try and rephrase this - I need to create a counter based on the Reference, grouped by the PerRef and QSet, ordered by the date (either ascending or descending)

Of course if there is a better way please state as I may be making this overly complex - if there a way to select First or Last Reference grouped on PerRef and Qset?

Comment: If there was 3 others entries like 3_03/01/2015_a_QS1_... would it Earliest value be 2 or 3 ?

Comment: This should be 3 - I guess it should be a sequence number but is applied against the surrogate grouping of PerRef&Qset if that makes sense. So 4_03/01/2015_a_QS1_would be 4 an so on.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution using `row_number()`:

```
SELECT t.*, orderT.Earliest
FROM #tmp_table t JOIN (SELECT Reference, PerRef, Qset, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY PerRef, Qset order by Date ) as Earliest
                        FROM #tmp_table
                        GROUP BY Reference, Date, PerRef, Qset) orderT ON t.Reference = orderT.Reference
                                                                  AND t.PerRef = orderT.PerRef
                                                                  AND t.Qset = orderT.Qset
```

What it does is:
 1. Compute the `Earliest` column for each `Reference`/`PerRef`/`Qset` combination
 2. "Apply" it to each line using `JOIN` on `Reference`/`PerRef`/`Qset`

Check out `row_number()` documentation if you have trouble understanding the query: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx
Generating the `Latest`column using a similar method shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I can not try this till Monday now. Quick question. The #tmp_table and t - are these names of the source table (#tmp_table) and a virtual table created in the query (t). Sorry to ask but just want to be clear

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question but
`t` is an alias for `#tmp_table` which is the name I used for your `Reference/ Date/PerRef/QSet/Question/Answer` table since I didn't knew its actual name.